# How to remove mysterious tilda from R Plotly tooltip?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I’m using R's ggplot and passing it through ggplotly to generate interactive charts on my Shiny app. However, I have no idea why my tooltip keeps displaying a “~” sign before the variable name and I can’t seem to remove it. This appears for all my charts in my Shiny app. How can I remove the “~”? I've tried to customise the tooltip for the plotly argument but nothing seems to work...

Does anyone know the solution to this?

[image]

Here's my sample code:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  ageGroups = factor(c("18-25","26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56 and Above"), 
levels=c("18-25","26-35", "36-45", "46-55", "56 and Above")),
  ageCount = c(25,66,43,21,5)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=ageGroups, y=ageCount, fill=ageGroups)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.8) +
  xlab("Age Groups") +
  ylab("No. of Users") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "y")
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please share the code you used?

Comment: Hi RLave, I've updated my question with the sample code. Does this help?

Comment: To me it shows correctly just `ageCount: 43`, no "~". Maybe update your `plotly` version?

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've updated my plotly version and it seems to be working now. Thanks!